# how to use sqlite's parameter parsing

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

sqlite supports parsing parameters for you:

```
$ cur.execute("select name from people where age=?;", (age,))
```

How can I access the resulting parsed sql? Something like:

```
$ age = 18
$ cur.format("select name from people where age=?;", (age,))
"select name from people where age=18;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no resulting sql to access because the query is never assembled into a single string. The sqlite library receives the sql string and the parameters separately.